# Java code will not print out answer or read int properly

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

This is the whole project, it should work as far as I can see but i'm hoping that posting it here could let me see something I missed, I have a moderate amount of experience with java

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// write your code here
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number1;
    int number2;
    int answer;
    String operator;
```

This figures out what numbers and operators the user wants

```
 System.out.println("Please Enter your first number");
        number1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter your second number");
        number2 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter your operator: + , - , * , / ");
            operator = input.next();
```

The if Statement should determine which operator the user wants and applys it to the two numbers and then calls the randomEquation Method to make it the wrong answer

```
           if (operator == "+") {
                answer = number1 + number2;
                System.out.println("Your answer is: " + randomEquation(answer));
            } else if (operator == "-") {
                answer = number1 - number2;
                System.out.println("Your answer is: " + randomEquation(answer));
            } else if (operator == "*") {
                answer = number1 * number2;
                System.out.println("Your answer is: " + randomEquation(answer));
            } else if (operator == "/") {
                answer = number1 / number2;
                System.out.println("Your answer is: " + randomEquation(answer));
            }



}
```

This method randomly applies one of these to the answer to create the wrong answer

```
  public static int randomEquation(int number) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int random = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    int answer = number;
    if (random <= 100 && random >= 81) {
        answer = number * 25;
        return answer;
    }
    else if(random <= 80 && random >= 61){
        answer += 13;
        return answer;
    }
    else if(random <= 60 && random >= 41){
        answer /= 2;
        return answer;
    }
    else if(random <= 40 && random >= 21){
        answer -= 16;
        return answer;
    }
    else{
        answer %= 4;
        return answer;
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use .equals with Strings.

Instead of:

```
operator == "+"
```

Try:

```
"+".equals(operator)
```